# How to install docker version 17.04 on Amazon Linux?

Tags: docker

I tried installing docker on Amazon Linux but found that currently `sudo yum install docker` installs version `1.12`. However, I need docker version `17.04`. How can I upgrade my docker version or install version 17.04 on Amazon Linux ?

Answer (score 0):

Docker instillation comes with a predefined Cloud formation template this can be found in , the version is 17 here

https://editions-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/aws/stable/Docker.tmpl

you can always run an upgrade command if you do not want to sue a cloud formation template

```
 $ docker-machine upgrade default
```

Comment: I think he is asking about how to install docker 17-ce inside an EC2 not using a cloud template formation